# Trouble in installing the openinviter

Tags: php, apache2, openinviter

While installing openinviter I get the following error:

```
"Unable to write stats. /var/www/open/openinviter_stats.sqlite is not writable"
```

How to fix this installation error?

Screenshots of the error:

[image: viewerror]

Comment: That link to your screenshots has a heck of a lot of blinking things it really wants me to click.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the user account the web server is running under does not have permission to write to the file. Try changing the permissions on the file and seeing if that does it.